# Swift 2 CFType conversion

Tags: swift, core-foundation

In Swift 1.2 I had a C function with the following signature:

```
__nonnull CFArrayRef FDCreateSupportedAudioFileExtensions() CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

I know that this function returns an array of `CFStringRef` instances, so I called it from Swift like this:

```
let supportedAudioTypes = FDCreateSupportedAudioFileExtensions() as! [String]
```

and everything worked as expected.  However, in Swift 2 this code fails at runtime due to the forced cast (`EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`).  I'm able to get things working with the following:

```
let supportedAudioTypes = FDCreateSupportedAudioFileExtensions() as NSArray as! [String]
```

I'm unsure what changed from Swift 1.2 to 2.0.  Is this a bug in the current version of Swift or have I missed something?  Everything I've read implies that CFTypes are toll-free bridged to their Swift counterparts so I'm not sure why what used to work is now failing.

Comment: There is some discussion of this issue at https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/55297